# STM32 TIM1 Internal Clock (CK_INT)

Tags: timer, stm32, clock

[image]
According to the datasheet snippet above, TIM1 can be clocked by the internal clock (**CK_INT**). What is this internal clock? I have a feeling that it's just the **APB1 Timer Clocks (Mhz)** in the below clock tree, but is that correct? Why is it called an internal clock in the datasheet? 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From the 48MHz limit I'm assuming it's an STM32F0 series MCU.

The clock tree is documented a few chapters back, in *Reset and clock control (RCC) / Clocks*.

[image]

> Why is it called an internal clock in the datasheet?

Because it is, well... internal. As opposed to an external clock, which is coming from an external source.

Comment: Yes it was F0, I should've specified! Even though this clock is "internal", it could still be derived from an external clock HSE right? That's why I thought the name internal clock was a bit weird.

Comment: Upon digging a little more after this, I read that "Internal Clock (CK_INT)" is supposed to be "CK_TIM18 from RCC" (Found here:  https://imgur.com/a/edeA8Nf). Is  CK_TIM18 supposed to be what's pointed to by "to TIM1,3,6,7,14,15,16,17" in the picture you linked?